# Concrete questions that turn into math problems

Tags: teaching, applications

I'm writing an article about the way we teach math, trying to find out why so many people are discouraged from learning, and have no interest for math and logic.

At some point, I want to show that math problems can originate in everyday questions. I want to point out concrete problems that all of us face and, through abstraction, enter the realm of math.

I've written a couple of these questions, discarded some and kept others, but am not quite satisfied with my choices. I thought to ask someone, and who better than you guys here :).

Could I get suggestions?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: A very good question, but not, I think, for this site. I recommend having a look at the faq and then asking over at math.stackexchange. 

Comment: @Gerry Oops. I didn't know there were 2 math sites in StackExchange (I come from StackOverflow, I'm a software engineer). Thanks for the tip!